# When does gdb show something 'on the stack'?

Tags: assembly, stack, gdb, callstack, backtrace

With the following assembly:

```
mov $2, %rax
push %rcx
call func
```

The 'stack' section in gdb looks like this:

```
─── Stack ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[0] from 0x0000000000400109 in func
[1] from 0x00000000004000be in _start
```

And it doesn't matter whether I add or remove the `push %rcx` instruction. Why does gdb only show the 'function address stack', and not show any modifications to the stack when manually pushed? That is, both `push %rcx` and `call func` change the stack register `rsp` but only the latter actually changes what gdb shows in the "stack" section.

Could someone please explain the reason for this?

Comment: That's some custom gdb modification and it prints the **call** stack, otherwise known as backtrace. It only shows the nested function calls. To look at the actual stack do something like `x/8x $rsp`

Comment: @Jester: Yes, but how does it figure out which qwords on the stack are from `call` and which are from `push`, for hand-written asm without debug info?  I'd guess it might look for possible return addresses, i.e. values that point into the text section?  Or maybe the OP isn't showing us a complete enough full picture.

Answer (score 0):

> The 'stack' section in gdb looks like this:

The 'stack' here stands for 'call stack', not 'stack memory'.